# Is this 'background-position' line ambiguous?

Tags: html, css, background-position

I [just read](http://www.sitepoint.com/css-using-percentages-in-background-image/) that you are *not* allowed to mix values, ex: `background-position: top 50%;`

However, I am not sure whether the following lines are ambiguous:

```
background-position: 0 50%; //can the 0 be confused as 0px?
background-position: 0 50px; //can the 0 be confused as 0%?
```

My concern is that they might cohere in a forbidden way and cause unexpected bugs.

Do you think this can happen and what makes you think that?

Comment: Never heard, that such mix would not be allowed. Also, nothing is said, that percentage and pixels could not be mixed.

Comment: @kirilloid sitepoint is good reference, but you are correct about the second thing, maybe they can be mixed

Comment: Yes, but I neither met such thing doesn't work since 2007, when I started studying CSS nor w3 spec forbid that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are allowed to combine keywords with percentage values or length values in **CSS2.1** ... but you weren't in **CSS2** (I mean, CSS 2.0). That should be the source of the confusion.

### From W3C [**CSS2.0** on background-position](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-CSS2-20080411/colors.html#propdef-background-position)

> Value:    [ [<percentage> | <length> ]{1,2} | [ [top | center | bottom] || [left | center | right] ] ] | inherit
>   (...)
>   Values have the following meanings:
>   - <percentage> <percentage> *blah*
>   - <length> <length> *blah*
>   - top left and left top (and 2 dozens of keyword combinations) *blah*
>
> If only one percentage or length value is given, it sets the horizontal position only, the vertical position will be 50%.
>   If two values are given, the horizontal position comes first.
>   **Combinations of length and percentage values are allowed, (e.g., '50% 2cm').**
>   Negative positions are allowed.
>   **Keywords cannot be combined with percentage values or length values** (all possible combinations are given above).

### From W3C [**CSS2.1** on background-position](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/colors.html#propdef-background-position)

> Value:    [ [ <percentage> | <length> | left | center | right ] [ <percentage> | <length> | top | center | bottom ]? ] | [ [ left | center | right ] || [ top | center | bottom ] ] | inherit
>   (...)
>   If only one value is specified, the second value is assumed to be 'center'.
>   **If at least one value is not a keyword, then the first value represents the horizontal position and the second represents the vertical position.**
>   Negative <percentage> and <length> values are allowed.

### Comparison

If you compare the possible Values in CSS2.0 and CSS2.1, it's pretty clear you could combine (percentage and length) OR (keywords) and can now combine any of the three types of value with any of the three types (OT: and you've been allowed forever to only use 1 value, the second one then being 50%/center).

Bold text and lack of any other indication in CSS2.1 also implies that, when you've 2 values, you can have 0, 1 or 2 keywords thus that you can encounter, as a browser, the case where there's exactly 1 keyword.

From what I recall, I never encountered any problem with IE6+, only with the W3C validator ([jigsaw](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/)) when it validated against CSS2 by default or something like that.
The CSS validator seems happy with `body { background-position : 40cm left; }`

**CSS2.1** has been a **W3C Recommendation** for nearly a year (7 june 2011) so that shouldn't cause new confusion.

Comment: Nice job digging up the CSS2 specification for comparison! I wouldn't say it's clear that you can combine values (so many brackets and OR operators!) but this should _further_ put the nail in the coffin for OP's concerns.

Answer (score 6):

0px and 0% are identical.  It's like in physics- there are no units to zero, there's no point in saying 0cm or 0in, it's just nothing.

Comment: My worries are that they might cause unexpected errors. I know that `0 0 === left top === 0px 0px === 0% 0%`

Comment: Definitely not, that's all I have to say. :-)

Comment: @ajax333221--you should just accept dbaseman's answer and give him your bounty when the time is up, because he already answered your question correctly.

Comment: @ScottS I don't think he answered, he just said a fact that might not even apply to computers...

Comment: @ajax333221--it seems to me his answer directly applies to the question you posed "Is this 'background-position' line ambiguous?" The answer is "no" because of the reason dbaseman stated. I'm not sure what more "proof" he could offer that there is nothing for you to worry about with the two lines of code you proposed.

Comment: @ScottS is not ambiguous for humans, but who knows how the parser will interpret that. The parser can't do any reasoning, it just follow orders. It is wrong to assume the parser is following certain orders just because they make sense... I have learnt this the hard way using JavaScript

Comment: @ajax333221--I agree. But do you need to examine the technical documentation of every browser to get your answer? If it is _not_ a problem, what more proof or what further answer can be given? Now, if a bug documentation exists that shows it to be a problem, then someone could post that here in contradiction to dbaseman's answer, but if none exists, then there is not much more proof that can be offered to prove it is not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

No, your background-position is not ambiguous. You're allowed to mix/match unit types. You've also specified two values, which means you can  *always* expect the browser to interpret in the following order:

- the first value designates horizontal-position
- the second value designates vertical-position

Where this can be ambiguous:

**If only one value is specified, the second value is assumed to be 'center'**. [source](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/background-position#background-position)

Keep in mind this disregards what unit type is being used. If only one value is specified, the other value is always `center` by default.

Notice how in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SaVWJ/) the only supplied value (`top`) is strictly for vertical-positioning, which makes the other value (the horizontal-position) `center` by default. Conversely, as seen in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7u4UF/), only specifying `left` (a value strictly for horizontal-positioning) will make the vertical-position `center` by default. If only [one percentage value](http://jsfiddle.net/KrCnV/), or [one pixel value](http://jsfiddle.net/MQeaT/), is specified, it appears to apply to the horizontal-position by default.

To be safe and avoid ambiguity, I would recommend always having both values specified. However, as long as you understand the above, it should never be ambiguous.

Comment: 1)"dbaseman's answer is correct", I know it is, but it is an offtopic fact not related to my question, 2)everything below your horizontal line is offtopic too, except for the last line, 3)your last line advice is good, but my question remains

Comment: @ajax333221 The answer should better answer your question now.